# How can I double-enhance a class with cglib?

Tags: hibernate, cglib

Here's the code:

```
    Patient patient = factory.createPatient();           

    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(patient.getClass());
    enhancer.setCallback(new DefaultMethodInterceptor(patient));
    patient = (Patient) enhancer.create();

    assertThat(patient.getFirstName()).isNotNull();


    Enhancer enhancer2 = new Enhancer();
    enhancer2.setSuperclass(patient.getClass());
    enhancer2.setCallback(new DefaultMethodInterceptor(patient));
    patient = (Patient) enhancer2.create();

    assertThat(patient.getFirstName()).isNotNull();
```

It fails on the last assert with

```
net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file my/package/entity/Patient$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ca1e6685$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f52743be
```

I ask this because I want to enhance Hibernate's entities, but sometimes it returns already enhanced ones by itself and my second enhancement fails. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check whether your class is already enhanced via `Enhancer.isEnhanced()` method.

If it is, your 2nd enhancement should be applied to *original* class, not the already enhanced version like you do in the above code. You can still compound your enhancements within `MethodInterceptor.intercept()` implementation but you have to do that with care.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I had a hard time discovering which class was the original one, I eventually got it working cutting of everything from $$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ from the name of the class.

Answer (score 2):

This was quite helpful to me, as well.  Just wanted to point out that calling getSuperclass()  up the chain and checking Enhancer.isEnhanced() for each should locate the proper superclass.